# Online game bot performance

Tags: javascript, performance, bots, puppeteer, window-object

I'm creating bot for online dynamic game. In this case dynamic means that hero ingame can move around and background is changing when moving. Global variables like `monsters` are changing dynamic when moving as well.

My bot is using puppeteer. Since I need this monsters object I have function which get those monsters from page context every 2 - 3 seconds (randomize for anti-detection).

This solution is far from being perfect. Two main downsides are:

- My bot kill monster and I want to go to next one it still see this monster which has got killed because next refresh is for example 1500ms from that point of time.
- Performance of getting monsters is bad.

To solve first one I could just execute function which download monsters every time after killing one. On the other hand then second downside will be even stronger because I will perform much more getting monster which already is slow.

It all comes to second issue which is performance. You may ask how do I know that performance is bad?

When hero is moving it's relatively smooth but when monsters are being downloaded I see micro lag, like for a part of second hero stop. It's really maybe 100ms of lag but I can see it with human eye and if I will perform getting monster more frequently this lag will get stronger (to be clear - lag will not be longer but more often).

Downloading object from global window is long. The reason why is that game maintainers developed it so `monsters` are within big object `npc` which contains everything that is in dashboard and contains even empty elements so the total amount of this `npc` object is between 100k-200k elements. I'm doing lots of filters in order to get final monster data which I care about.

I'll show how I'm actually getting this monsters. So I execute 3 async functions:

```
const allNpc = await getAllNpc(page);
let monsters = await filterMonsters(page, allNpc, monstersToHunt);
monsters.hunt = await deleteAvoidedMonsters(page, monsters.hunt, monstersToOmit);
```

First one `getAllNpc` just get entire npc object (this big one which I mentioned above)

```
return await page.evaluate(() => {
    if(window.g) return g.npc;
});
```

second function filter actual monsters and monsters which I want to kill from npc:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const validNpc = allNpc.filter(el => !!el);
    const allMonsters = validNpc.filter(e => e.lvl !== 0);

    const names = new Set(monstersNames);
    const huntMonsters = validNpc
        .filter(it => names.has(it.nick))
        .map(({ nick, x, y, grp, id }) => ({ nick, x, y, grp, id }));

    resolve({all: allMonsters, hunt: huntMonsters});
});
```

I'm using `Set` here to get rid of O(n) / O(n^2) algorithms and I think this is fastest I can achieve with javascript. Third function is same as this one but additionally filtering special monsters which I want to avoid.

Now my questions are:

- is there a way to get this object on every this object and only this object change? I know there is function in puppeteer that can watch for DOM changes but is there something to watch global window object?
- can I do anything more to speed it up? I read about `worker_threads` in NodeJS, can it help getting rid of this micro lag or something else? Clustering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I realized after a while is that bot was "lagging" because I was passing this huge `g.npc` array as argument to function. By that I mean I was resolving it from `getAllNpc` and then passing it to `filterMonsters`.

When I changed it so I execute `.filter` in `getAllNpc` inside evaluated script within page context and then resolving and passing array with hundreds not millions elements it is much faster and do not cause any lag or freeze.